# Issue with Visual Studio, C# and Azure SQL database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

Straight to the point: I'm in dire need of some help. I'm making this program with Azure backend and I have a reader script that reads data from a table and adds it to a variable. It works fine, the first time. If I press the button to get a reading a second time, or even any button after I've pressed the get button, I get a crash saying:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been
>   initialized."

Here's the code for the reader:

```
    private void TransactionGetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string getterQuery = "SELECT balance FROM cloudbase WHERE name = '" + NameTextBox.Text + "' AND surname = '" + SurnameTextBox.Text + "';";
    SqlCommand getCommand = new SqlCommand(getterQuery, cloudDatabaseConnection);
    try
    {
        cloudDatabaseConnection.Open();
        using (cloudDatabaseConnection)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = getCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                currentBalance = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
            reader.Close();
            string currentBalanceToString = currentBalance.ToString();
            BalanceLabel.Text = currentBalanceToString + "MKD";
        }
    }catch(SqlException e1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e1.StackTrace + "\n\n" + e1.Message);
    }
    cloudDatabaseConnection.Close();    
}
```

Some of the variables here are declared outside the function.
What does this mean? I open and close connections and read/stop reading properly. I'm lost.

To have some comparable code, here's another button that opens / closes a connection, but works no matter how many times I've pressed it. Both snippets are from the same file, but different functions:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        amountToInt = int.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text);
        insertdatabaseCloud.Connection = cloudDatabaseConnection;
        insertdatabaseCloud.CommandText = "UPDATE cloudbase SET balance = balance + " + amountToInt + " WHERE name = '" + NameTextBox.Text +"' AND surname = '" + SurnameTextBox.Text +"';";
        if(AmountTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all fields");
        }
        else if(NameTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all fields");
        }
        else if(SurnameTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all fields");
        }
        else
        {
            cloudDatabaseConnection.Open();
            int i = insertdatabaseCloud.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cloudDatabaseConnection.Close();
            if (i != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database data updated successfully!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like you're sharing the same connection around in the class, and it's being shared around in ways that are causing the issue. I suggest that you create a new connection in each method (being careful to wrap them in using statements) from the connection string, rather than sharing it around.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should just create the same connection multiple times for the functions? Will try, thanks for the quick reply! @MartinCostello

Comment: @MartinCostello was right! I split it up among functions and it works flawlessly! Giant thanks to him!

Comment: Martin: make it an answer please

Comment: @CSharpRocks Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're reusing an `SqlConnection` across multiple operations. This isn't safe, so the operations are tripping over each other, causing the issues you are experiencing.

Store the connection string as a `string` in a field/property in your class, and create a new `SqlConnection` (in a `using` block so you don't leak connections) using the connection string within each invocation of your method(s).

This should isolate the operations from each other no matter how many times you click the button (except for however they may overlap within SQL Server itself, depending on what your queries' effects are).